# Convert a multi_key map into a "normal" map joining the multiple keys

Tags: c++, maps, duplicates

I am looking for a way to "zip" a multikey map to a normal map. My multimap looks like this:

```
Key                 v a l u e s 
<string>            <string>

140,1,08,2500       1456 
140,1,10,3040       1456 
.............       ....
.............       ....
140,1,08,2500       8g   
140,1,13,3040       8g   
.............       ....
```

The first and the penultimate key are identical. My goal is to merge these two (and all other duplicate key pairs) lines so that the result is:

```
140,1,08,2500       14568g
```

The values belonging to the original two keys being merged. Now, I could write some nice loop and iterate and copy and delete stuff and so on, but I wonder if anyone knows a smart, maybe even fast way to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple...

```
map<string, string> new_map;

for(auto it = mmap.begin(), end = mmap.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
  new_map[it->first].append(it->second);
}
```

Why make it more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

If the elements in the multimap are stored in the right order (i.e. you know that `1456` is always iterated before `8g` then you can do a simple loop:

```
std::map< key_t, string > result;
for ( multimap_t::const_iterator it = mm.begin(); it != mm.end(); ++it ) {
   result[ it->first ].append( it->second );
}
```

The problem is that I don't think that the order of the elements sharing a common key is guaranteed.

Comment: AFAIK, for the same key, it maintains insertion order, though this could be implementation defined.

Comment: @Nim: the problem is that the standard does not guarantee that.

Comment: true, I couldn't see any mention of it even in the new standard either, which is why I said, it's most likely implementation defined, it's up to the OP to determine if there is any other *natural* ordering to apply...