# Trying to pass data from a multimap to a map is not working as suggested

Tags: c++, oop, std, multimap

In this post [Convert a multi_key map into a "normal" map joining the multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964101/convert-a-multi-key-map-into-a-normal-map-joining-the-multiple-keys)

They suggest how to convert a multimap to the map by passing the values of the first to the second one. I tried that in my code, but it doesn't work:

```
multimap<double, Point>::iterator it;
  
for(it = _mapIntersectionVertices.begin(); it != _mapIntersectionVertices.end(); ++it)
{
  _mapNewPoints[it->first].insert(it->second);
}
```

I get the error
**"no member named 'insert' in 'Point'"**  I don't know why, I am not trying to call a method, just following the example in the post. As a side thing I am not very comfortable with the fact they use the same iterator for the map and the multimap inside the for, but when using instead a map iterator it2 to do:

```
 _mapNewPoints[it2->first].insert(it->second)
```

nothing changes

where i have the following attributes in some class I am trying to fill in.

```
multimap<double, Point> _mapIntersectionVertices;
map<double, Point> _mapNewPoints;
```

and the Point class is:

```
class Point
{
    private:
        Vector2d _coordinates; //using Eigen library

    public:
        int _label;
        Point(const double x = 0.0, const double y = 0.0);
        Point(Vector2d coordinates);

        void setCoordinates(const double x, const double y) {_coordinates(x, y);}
        const Vector2d& getCoordinates() const {return _coordinates;}


};
```

I want to copy the content of the multimap into the map, so that I can add more data to the later without messing with the first one and in a easier way than if  _mapNewPoints were declared as a multimap(   using the [] operator that is available for a map but not for a  multimap).

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_mapNewPoints[it->first].insert` would imply that `Point` has an `insert` method which is not the case. I believe you may want something like this:

```
for (it = _mapIntersectionVertices.begin(); it != _mapIntersectionVertices.end(); ++it)
{
    _mapNewPoints.insert(*it);
}
```

Comment: Why does it work in the post I linked when using <string, string>?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO because the string member has an `.append` method.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO, but if you just want to pass the data from one map to another, there is no need for that.

Comment: how do you suggest to do it then?

Comment: And in the linked post: , map<string, string> new_map;

for(auto it = mmap.begin(), end = mmap.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
  new_map[it->first].append(it->second);
}..... How come they use the multimap iterator for new_map whicht  is a map

Comment: @J.C.VegaO You'd have to make your own insert method in Point

Comment: @J.C.VegaO I'm not sure I understand your question, they iterate over the map to extract each value to add to the new map.